# Intellij Idea and Spring and Maven: Add Frameworks Support

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I don't know, why maven don't add Spring to the Intellij "Add Frameworks Support" window. I need this support to let Intellij generate some files like dispatcher-servlet.xml. I don't know which is responsible to add Spring to this window, maven or Intellij? I added spring dependency, all plugin are installed. I have Ultimate Intellij 2017.1 Version.

pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Go to File > Project Structure

You're gonna see Spring (Your project's name). In this case, my project's name is `HelloWorldDemo`. Then you just right click at Spring (`HelloWorldDemo`) and choose delete

[image]

Then back to the main screen. Right click at your project's name > Add Framework Support. Then you're gonna see Spring MVC appears.

[image]

I hope this helps. This is my first answer at StackOverFlow. Sorry at all if I do some mistakes in posting answers.

Comment: Can you explaing why this happens?

Comment: Mine only worked when I clicked on Apply before clicking Ok, maybe you could add this to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Framework is not available is the Intellij community edition , only in the ULTIMATE edition!!!